# Django - constructing multi column indexes

Tags: python, django, django-models, indexing

Say we have a model that looks thus:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    """Users will query for entries with various combinations of filters"""
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    urgent = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is the correct way to create indexes that will cater for any combination of the above fields in filters? E.g. `.filter(date_created__year='2021', important=False, user=1)`

My first thought was the below but I have a suspicion I'm doing something wrong here...

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [models.Index(fields=['-date_created']),
               models.Index(fields=['-date_created', 'important']),
               models.Index(fields=['-date_created', 'important', 'urgent']),
               models.Index(fields=['-date_created', 'important', 'urgent', 'user']),
               models.Index(fields=['-date_created', 'user']),
               models.Index(fields=['....etc...'])]
```

I read through the Django documentation and noted their use of the include argument that was introduced in Django 3.2, but was unable to find useful examples of it's use. Would it work in my situation?

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [models.Index(name='some_index', fields=['-date_created'], include=['important', 'urgent', 'user'])]
```

Thank you